# Volley's StringRequest is not returning JSONObject

Tags: android, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest, request-response

The code below is going to implement a simple online login system.

The php script path is defined in constant `authenticationURL` (line 34 in MainActivity.java).
It was tested with Postman and works as it should.
Also the `loginButton` and its `onClick()` method work fine, because the `Toast` ***Hey, I'm up here!*** is displayed.

But regardless of input fields' values validity, when the `loginButton` is clicked / tapped, the `Toast` is ALWAYS shown. Meaning that `StringRequest` is `null`.

**Tools used:**
xampp 7.2.11-0-VC15, Android Studio 3.2.1 & Genymotion 3.0.0 -> Custom Phone (API 28)

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.admin.test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText usernameEditText, passwordEditText;

    private static final String TAG = "OneTwoThree";

    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private StringRequest request;
    private static final String authenticationURL = "http://10.0.3.2:80/test/authenticationScript.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        usernameEditText = findViewById(R.id.usernameEditText);
        passwordEditText = findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
        Button loginButton = findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, authenticationURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            if(jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("success")) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SUCCESS" + jsonObject.getString("success"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR" + jsonObject.getString("error"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Request response error.");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hey, I'm up here!" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // Just for debugging purpose
                    }
                })

                {
                    @Override
                    public String getBodyContentType() {
                        return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                        hashMap.put("username", usernameEditText.getText().toString());
                        hashMap.put("password", passwordEditText.getText().toString());

                        return hashMap;
                    }
                };

                requestQueue.add(request);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/usernameEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:autofillHints="@string/username"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/username"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:targetApi="o" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:autofillHints="@string/password"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/usernameEditText"
        tools:targetApi="o" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="@string/log_in"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordEditText" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is the parts of Logcat (Sorry truncated due to text limitations):

```
2019-01-11 21:45:41.731 248-248/? E/hostapd: Configuration file: /vendor/etc/simulated_hostapd.conf
2019-01-11 21:45:41.735 248-248/? E/hostapd: Using interface wlan1 with hwaddr 02:00:00:00:01:00 and ssid "AndroidWifi"
2019-01-11 21:45:41.736 134-134/? E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { add } for interface=android.hardware.wifi.hostapd::IHostapd pid=248 scontext=u:r:execns:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:hal_wifi_hostapd_hwservice:s0 tclass=hwservice_manager permissive=1
2019-01-11 21:45:41.737 134-134/? E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { add } for interface=android.hidl.base::IBase pid=248 scontext=u:r:execns:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:hidl_base_hwservice:s0 tclass=hwservice_manager permissive=1
2019-01-11 21:45:42.155 320-320/? E/Netd: cannot find interface dummy0
2019-01-11 21:45:42.155 320-320/? E/XfrmController: netlink response contains error (Status[code: 95, msg: "[Operation not supported on transport endpoint] : Error netlink message"])
2019-01-11 21:45:42.155 320-320/? E/Netd: Failed to initialize XfrmController (Status[code: 95, msg: "[Operation not supported on transport endpoint] : Error netlink message"])
2019-01-11 21:45:42.155 320-320/? E/Netd: Unable to create netlink socket: Protocol not supported
2019-01-11 21:45:43.031 321-321/? E/ActivityRecognitionHardware: activity_recognition HAL is deprecated. class_init is effectively a no-op
2019-01-11 21:45:43.672 351-351/system_process E/UsbAlsaJackDetectorJNI: Can't register UsbAlsaJackDetector native methods
2019-01-11 21:45:43.798 351-370/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
2019-01-11 21:45:43.799 351-370/system_process E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for telephony
2019-01-11 21:45:50.229 400-400/? E/EmulatedCamera_Factory: 2 cameras are being emulated. 0 of them are fake cameras.
2019-01-11 21:45:50.229 400-400/? E/EmulatedCamera_HotplugThread: createFileIfNotExists: Could not create file '/data/misc/media/emulator.camera.hotplug.0', error: 'Permission denied' (13)
2019-01-11 21:45:50.229 400-400/? E/EmulatedCamera_HotplugThread: createFileIfNotExists: Could not create file '/data/misc/media/emulator.camera.hotplug.1', error: 'Permission denied' (13)
2019-01-11 21:45:50.230 400-400/? E/CamProvider@2.4-impl: setUpVendorTags: Vendor tag operations not fully defined. Ignoring definitions.
2019-01-11 21:45:50.230 400-400/? E/CamProvider@2.4-impl: initialize: Vendor tag setup failed, will not be available.
2019-01-11 21:45:50.264 399-399/? E/SoundTriggerHalImpl: couldn't load sound trigger module sound_trigger.primary (No such file or directory)
2019-01-11 21:45:50.294 417-417/? E/network_profile_handler: init_all_network_profile_state: wlan: wlan0 phone:rmnet0
2019-01-11 21:45:50.472 408-408/? E/light: light_open lights bluetooth failed: -22
2019-01-11 21:45:50.472 408-408/? E/light: Light passthrough failed to load legacy HAL.
2019-01-11 21:45:50.472 408-408/? E/light: light_open lights wifi failed: -22
2019-01-11 21:45:50.472 408-408/? E/light: Light passthrough failed to load legacy HAL.
2019-01-11 21:45:50.520 442-442/? E/MediaCodecsXmlParser: Cannot find the role for a decoder of type audio/x-ape
2019-01-11 21:45:50.520 442-442/? E/MediaCodecsXmlParser: Cannot find the role for a decoder of type audio/ffmpeg
2019-01-11 21:45:50.520 442-442/? E/MediaCodecsXmlParser: Cannot find the role for a decoder of type video/divx
2019-01-11 21:45:50.520 442-442/? E/MediaCodecsXmlParser: Cannot find the role for a decoder of type audio/vnd.dts
2019-01-11 21:45:50.520 442-442/? E/MediaCodecsXmlParser: Cannot find the role for a decoder of type video/x-flv
2019-01-11 21:45:50.520 442-442/? E/MediaCodecsXmlParser: Cannot find the role for a decoder of type audio/vnd.rn-realaudio
2019-01-11 21:45:50.520 442-442/? E/MediaCodecsXmlParser: Cannot find the role for a decoder of type video/vnd.rn-realvideo
2019-01-11 21:45:50.520 442-442/? E/MediaCodecsXmlParser: Cannot find the role for a decoder of type video/vc1
2019-01-11 21:45:50.520 442-442/? E/MediaCodecsXmlParser: Cannot find the role for a decoder of type video/ffmpeg
2019-01-11 21:45:50.520 442-442/? E/MediaCodecsXmlParser: Cannot find the role for a decoder of type audio/x-ms-wma
2019-01-11 21:45:50.520 442-442/? E/MediaCodecsXmlParser: Cannot find the role for a decoder of type video/x-ms-wmv
2019-01-11 21:45:50.634 406-406/? E/hwcomposer: unknown display attribute 6
2019-01-11 21:45:50.674 429-429/? E/ExtCamUtils@3.4: loadFromCfg: Unable to load external camera config file '/vendor/etc/external_camera_config.xml'. Error: XML_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
2019-01-11 21:45:50.677 429-429/? E/CameraProviderManager: filterLogicalCameraIdsLocked: Failed to getCameraCharacteristics for id 0
2019-01-11 21:45:50.681 399-468/? E/EffectsConfig: Could not parse effect configuration in any of the default locations.
2019-01-11 21:45:50.681 399-468/? E/EffectsFactoryConfigLoader: Failed to parse XML configuration file
2019-01-11 21:45:50.683 429-429/? E/CameraProviderManager: filterLogicalCameraIdsLocked: Failed to getCameraCharacteristics for id 0
2019-01-11 21:45:50.684 429-476/? E/CameraProviderManager: filterLogicalCameraIdsLocked: Failed to getCameraCharacteristics for id 0
2019-01-11 21:45:50.684 429-429/? E/CameraProviderManager: filterLogicalCameraIdsLocked: Failed to getCameraCharacteristics for id 0
2019-01-11 21:45:50.685 429-476/? E/CameraService: onDeviceStatusChanged: State transition to the same status 0x1 not allowed
2019-01-11 21:45:50.695 413-413/? E/EffectsConfig: Could not parse effect configuration in any of the default locations.
2019-01-11 21:45:50.795 419-419/? E/libEGL: load_driver(/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
2019-01-11 21:45:50.934 419-419/? E/HWComposer: getSupportedPerFrameMetadata: getSupportedPerFrameMetadata failed for display 0: Unsupported (8)
2019-01-11 21:45:52.438 351-376/system_process E/LocalDisplayAdapter: Default and active color mode is no longer available! Reverting to first available mode.
2019-01-11 21:45:52.507 534-539/? E/libEGL: load_driver(/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
2019-01-11 21:45:52.850 351-351/system_process E/PackageManager: There should probably be a verifier, but, none were found
2019-01-11 21:45:52.889 413-413/? E/SoundTriggerHwService: could not read implementation properties
2019-01-11 21:45:52.976 351-364/system_process E/SystemServer: Unable to preload default resources
2019-01-11 21:45:53.009 351-351/system_process E/VibratorService: vibratorOff command failed (1).
2019-01-11 21:45:53.219 351-590/system_process E/EventHub: could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
2019-01-11 21:45:53.291 145-145/? E/vold: Failed to read field SystemLocale: No such file or directory
2019-01-11 21:45:53.322 351-592/system_process E/StorageManagerService: Failed to read field SystemLocale
    android.os.ServiceSpecificException: Failed to read field SystemLocale (code 2)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1956)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1910)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1860)
        at android.os.IVold$Stub$Proxy.fdeGetField(IVold.java:1094)
        at com.android.server.StorageManagerService.getField(StorageManagerService.java:2408)
        at com.android.server.StorageManagerService.copyLocaleFromMountService(StorageManagerService.java:982)
        at com.android.server.StorageManagerService.handleDaemonConnected(StorageManagerService.java:975)
        at com.android.server.StorageManagerService.access$900(StorageManagerService.java:171)
        at com.android.server.StorageManagerService$StorageManagerServiceHandler.handleMessage(StorageManagerService.java:572)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
2019-01-11 21:45:53.350 351-590/system_process E/EventHub: could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
2019-01-11 21:45:53.543 351-351/system_process E/WifiStateMachine: getWifiLinkLayerStats called without an interface
2019-01-11 21:45:53.555 351-351/system_process E/SupplicantStaIfaceHal: Can't call setDebugParams, ISupplicant is null
2019-01-11 21:45:53.642 351-351/system_process E/UsbPortManager: connectToProxy: usb hal service not found. Did the service fail to start?
    java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at android.os.HwBinder.getService(Native Method)
        at android.os.HwBinder.getService(HwBinder.java:91)
        at android.hardware.usb.V1_0.IUsb.getService(IUsb.java:48)
        at android.hardware.usb.V1_0.IUsb.getService(IUsb.java:52)
        at com.android.server.usb.UsbPortManager.connectToProxy(UsbPortManager.java:531)
        at com.android.server.usb.UsbPortManager.<init>(UsbPortManager.java:137)
        at com.android.server.usb.UsbService.<init>(UsbService.java:142)
        at com.android.server.usb.UsbService$Lifecycle.onStart(UsbService.java:73)
        at com.android.server.SystemServiceManager.startService(SystemServiceManager.java:126)
        at com.android.server.SystemServiceManager.startService(SystemServiceManager.java:113)
        at com.android.server.SystemServiceManager.startService(SystemServiceManager.java:72)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.startOtherServices(SystemServer.java:1308)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:432)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:295)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:838)
2019-01-11 21:45:53.646 351-351/system_process E/HardwarePropertiesManagerService-JNI: Unable to get Thermal service.
2019-01-11 21:45:53.718 351-351/system_process E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/gatekeeper.password.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2019-01-11 21:45:53.718 351-351/system_process E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/password.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2019-01-11 21:45:53.718 351-351/system_process E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/gatekeeper.pattern.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2019-01-11 21:45:53.719 351-351/system_process E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/gatekeeper.gesture.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2019-01-11 21:45:53.719 351-351/system_process E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/gesture.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2019-01-11 21:45:53.754 351-351/system_process E/IpConfigStore: Error opening configuration file: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/misc/ethernet/ipconfig.txt (No such file or directory)
2019-01-11 21:45:53.855 351-351/system_process E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/users/0/wallpaper_orig (No such file or directory)
2019-01-11 21:45:53.855 351-351/system_process E/WallpaperManagerService: Unable to apply new wallpaper
2019-01-11 21:45:53.865 351-614/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
2019-01-11 21:45:53.866 351-614/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
2019-01-11 21:45:53.933 436-457/? E/MediaExtractorFactory: couldn't opendir(/vendor/lib/extractors)
2019-01-11 21:45:53.972 351-370/system_process E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for wifi
2019-01-11 21:45:53.972 351-370/system_process E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for telephony
2019-01-11 21:45:53.991 320-342/? E/IptablesRestoreController: iptables error:
    ------- COMMAND -------
    *filter
    -I bw_INPUT -m quota2 ! --quota 2097152 --name globalAlert
    -I bw_OUTPUT -m quota2 ! --quota 2097152 --name globalAlert
    COMMIT

    -------  ERROR -------
    iptables-restore: line 290 failed
    ----------------------
2019-01-11 21:45:54.003 320-342/? E/IptablesRestoreController: iptables error:
    ------- COMMAND -------
    *filter
    -I bw_INPUT -m quota2 ! --quota 2097152 --name globalAlert
    -I bw_OUTPUT -m quota2 ! --quota 2097152 --name globalAlert
    COMMIT

    -------  ERROR -------
    ip6tables-restore: line 271 failed
    ----------------------
2019-01-11 21:45:54.048 672-690/? E/WebViewLoader-: Failed to send DDMS packet REAQ to debugger (-1 of 20): Broken pipe
2019-01-11 21:45:54.061 442-442/? E/media.codec: Failed to allocate omx component 'OMX.google.ac3.decoder'  err=InvalidComponentName(0x80001002)
2019-01-11 21:45:54.063 320-342/? E/BandwidthController: Updating quota globalAlert failed (Status[code: 2, msg: "[No such file or directory] : fopen("/proc/net/xt_quota/globalAlert", "we") failed"])
2019-01-11 21:45:54.072 404-404/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: getExtensionAGnss: AGnss interface not implemented by HAL
2019-01-11 21:45:54.072 404-404/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: getExtensionGnssMeasurement: GnssMeasurement interface not implemented by HAL
2019-01-11 21:45:54.072 404-404/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: getExtensionGnssConfiguration: GnssConfiguration interface not implemented by HAL
2019-01-11 21:45:54.072 404-404/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: getExtensionGnssGeofencing: GnssGeofencing interface not implemented by HAL
2019-01-11 21:45:54.073 404-404/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnss flp hw_get_module failed: -2
2019-01-11 21:45:54.073 404-404/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: getExtensionGnssBatching: GnssBatching interface is not implemented by HAL
2019-01-11 21:45:54.111 351-351/system_process E/LocationManagerService: no geocoder provider found
2019-01-11 21:45:54.127 351-351/system_process E/ActivityRecognitionHardware: activity_recognition HAL is deprecated. is_supported is effectively a no-op
2019-01-11 21:45:54.128 351-351/system_process E/ActivityRecognitionProxy: ServiceWatcher could not start.
2019-01-11 21:45:54.128 351-365/system_process E/GnssLocationProvider: Unable to initialize GNSS Xtra interface
2019-01-11 21:45:54.132 351-365/system_process E/GnssLocationProvider: no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
2019-01-11 21:45:54.167 351-365/system_process E/GnssLocationProvider: Unable to initialize GNSS Xtra interface
2019-01-11 21:45:54.167 351-365/system_process E/GnssLocationProvider: no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
2019-01-11 21:45:54.167 351-365/system_process E/GnssBatchingProvider: Failed to initialize GNSS batching
2019-01-11 21:45:54.173 442-442/? E/media.codec: Failed to allocate omx component 'OMX.google.mp2.decoder'  err=InvalidComponentName(0x80001002)
2019-01-11 21:45:54.231 442-456/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xea42c8a0:google.h264.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.configureVideoTunnelMode) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
2019-01-11 21:45:54.231 442-456/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xea42c8a0:google.h264.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.enableAndroidNativeBuffers) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
2019-01-11 21:45:54.237 442-456/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xea42c8a0:google.h263.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.configureVideoTunnelMode) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
2019-01-11 21:45:54.237 442-456/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xea42c8a0:google.h263.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.enableAndroidNativeBuffers) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
2019-01-11 21:45:54.244 442-456/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xea42c8a0:google.hevc.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.configureVideoTunnelMode) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
2019-01-11 21:45:54.244 442-456/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xea42c8a0:google.hevc.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.enableAndroidNativeBuffers) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
2019-01-11 21:45:54.248 442-442/? E/media.codec: Failed to allocate omx component 'OMX.google.mpeg2v.decoder'  err=InvalidComponentName(0x80001002)
2019-01-11 21:45:54.250 442-442/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xea42cba0:google.mpeg4.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.configureVideoTunnelMode) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
2019-01-11 21:45:54.250 442-442/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xea42cba0:google.mpeg4.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.enableAndroidNativeBuffers) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
2019-01-11 21:45:54.257 442-442/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xea42cba0:google.vp8.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.configureVideoTunnelMode) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
2019-01-11 21:45:54.257 442-442/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xea42cba0:google.vp8.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.enableAndroidNativeBuffers) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
2019-01-11 21:45:54.265 442-456/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xea42c8a0:google.vp9.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.configureVideoTunnelMode) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
2019-01-11 21:45:54.265 442-456/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xea42c8a0:google.vp9.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.enableAndroidNativeBuffers) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
2019-01-11 21:45:54.290 442-456/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xea42cba0:google.h263.encoder, ConfigAndroidIntraRefresh(0x6f60000a)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
2019-01-11 21:45:54.300 442-456/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xea42cba0:google.mpeg4.encoder, ConfigAndroidIntraRefresh(0x6f60000a)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
2019-01-11 21:45:54.317 442-456/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xea42cba0:google.vp8.encoder, ConfigAndroidIntraRefresh(0x6f60000a)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
2019-01-11 21:45:54.382 442-442/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xea42c900:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
2019-01-11 21:45:54.551 442-456/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xea42c900:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
2019-01-11 21:45:54.667 442-456/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xea42c900:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
2019-01-11 21:45:54.679 767-767/? E/wpa_supplicant: global ctrl interface @android:wpa_wlan0 matches ctrl interface wlan0 - do not open per-interface ctrl interface
2019-01-11 21:45:54.690 767-767/? E/wpa_supplicant: global ctrl interface @android:wpa_wlan0 matches ctrl interface wlan0 - do not open per-interface ctrl interface
2019-01-11 21:45:54.724 634-819/com.android.inputmethod.latin E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for user_dictionary
2019-01-11 21:45:54.863 412-412/? E/android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service: Failed to register radio mode change callback
2019-01-11 21:45:54.863 412-412/? E/android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service: Failed to set DFS flag; DFS channels may be unavailable.
2019-01-11 21:45:54.923 441-441/? E/wificond: No Offload Service available
2019-01-11 21:45:55.049 769-769/? E/CarrierIdProvider: read carrier list from ota pb failure: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/misc/carrierid/carrier_list.pb (No such file or directory)
2019-01-11 21:45:55.050 781-822/? E/libEGL: load_driver(/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
2019-01-11 21:45:55.276 351-604/system_process E/SupplicantStaIfaceHal: Can't call setupIface, ISupplicantStaIface is null
2019-01-11 21:45:55.578 351-351/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null

2019-01-11 21:45:55.859 442-456/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xea42c9c0:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.admin.test">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The URL and the script are working perfect. Watch these screenshots below...
[image: The output screenshot]

[image: Testing the script, URL, server... with Postman (form-data) and valid input]

[image: Testing the script, URL, server... with Postman (form-data) and invalid input]

[image: Testing the script, URL, server... with Postman (x-www-form-urlencoded) and valid input]

[image: Testing the script, URL, server... with Postman (x-www-form-urlencoded) and invalid input]

Comment: Either problem is on your url (is it correct?) or try to Log out `response` maybe you are logged in?

Comment: I see `Failed to read field SystemLocale` in your log, my first guess is the responded json is either missing the field or not well-formatted.

Comment: @Yupi - Yes the url is correct. I tested it with Postman and I could easily send query and get the result.

Comment: Try to `Log.d()` in Logcat `response`  see what will retrun

Comment: @DinoTw- I checked the URL as well as script once again. I left two captures of Postman while querying the server.  They're OK.

Comment: @Yupi Logcat returned 2019-01-12 22:28:21.752 1875-1901/com.example.admin.test E/EGL_emulation: tid 1901: eglSurfaceAttrib(1354): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)

Comment: Hello people. even though Samuel Liew blocked our communication, I read your posts again and using Dino's,  Yupi's and Wijdan's solutions I Logcated response and unfortunately found out that after testing the php script with Postman, response was mixed awkwardly with unwanted messages from scripts other than authentication.php. Sorry for the bother everyone. I'm still not sure if you great people can read me. Now my app works like a charm Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using form-data you have to add x-www-form-urlencoded. do it like this:

```
 @Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
    return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
}
```

you'r code going to be like below code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText usernameEditText, passwordEditText;

private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private StringRequest request;
private static final String authenticationURL = "http://10.0.3.2:80/test/authenticationScript.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    usernameEditText = findViewById(R.id.email);
    passwordEditText = findViewById(R.id.password);
    Button logIn = findViewById(R.id.signInUp);

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    logIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Just for debugging purpose
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hey, I'm up here!" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, authenticationURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        if(jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("success")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SUCCESS" + jsonObject.getString("success"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class));
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR" + jsonObject.getString("error"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }) {
              @Override
              public String getBodyContentType() {
             return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
             }

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                    hashMap.put("username", usernameEditText.getText().toString());
                    hashMap.put("password", passwordEditText.getText().toString());

                    return hashMap;
                }
            };

            requestQueue.add(request);
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: MainActivity.java and activity_main.xml were updated upon your suggestion. Still no luck. :(

Comment: I think your problem maybe be with StringRequest , So I propose you Test it With JsonObjectRequest . that you have send your params as json object.
-> public JsonObjectRequest(int method,
                         String url,
                         JSONObject jsonRequest,
                         Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener,
                         Response.ErrorListener errorListener)

Answer (score 0):

Try Using JsonObjectRequest

```
    JsonObjectRequest mJsonArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d("response", response.toString());

        }
    }
            , new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            NetworkResponse errorResponse = error.networkResponse;
            if (errorResponse != null && errorResponse.data != null) {
                Log.d("Error",errorResponse);
            }
        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(mJsonArrayRequest);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186642/discussion-on-answer-by-wijdan-volleys-stringrequest-is-not-returning-jsonobjec).

Comment: You do have access to join and chat in the room. Are you using a modern web browser, and are you behind any content filter?

Comment: You have write access, see here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/186642/discussion-on-answer-by-wijdan-volleys-stringrequest-is-not-returning-jsonobjec?tab=access